# How to run different tests on a single Document variable which was fetched with Jsoup.connect(string)

Tags: junit, jsoup

I have multiple test cases and I want to use a single Document variable with all of them.

There are more test units which will use this Document.

I had an idea to download the html code, in order to avoid connecting to the site multiple times and taking up server resources, but still I think that it wouldn't be an optional approach to testing.

```
public class ScrapperTest {

    public ScrapperTest() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {

    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
    }



    /**
     * Test of scrapeManufacturer method, of class Scrapper.
     */
    @Test
    public void testScrapeManufacturer() {
        System.out.println("scrapeManufacturer");
        Document html = null;
        Scrapper instance = new ScrapperImpl();
        String expResult = "";
        String result = instance.scrapeManufacturer(html);
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.

    }

    /**
     * Test of scrapeMinPrice method, of class Scrapper.
     */
    @Test
    public void testScrapeMinPrice() {
        System.out.println("scrapeMinPrice");
        Document html = null;
        Scrapper instance = new ScrapperImpl();
        String expResult = "";
        String result = instance.scrapeMinPrice(html);
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
        fail("The test case is a prototype.");
    }
```

Comment: *but still I think that it wouldn't be an optional approach to testing*: why?

Comment: Because I would have to repeat the same code on all test cases just to fetch and parse the html of the given URL

Comment: The sentence starts with "I had an idea to download the html code, in order to avoid connecting to the site multiple times and taking up server resources". So, if you have already downloaded, once and for all, the document, in order to avoid connecting to the site, why would you need to "fetch and parse the html of the given URL". Unless I miss something, you're contradicting yourself.

Comment: I want to avoid fetching and parsing the html (either from my hdd or the web) on every test case.

Comment: Then fetch and parse it once and for all the first time you need the document, and reuse that document in all the other test cases. I doubt this will provide any significant performance impact though. It could cause problems if any of the tests modifies the document, though. What exactly is the problem with fetching and parsing the HTML in each test case? What concrete problem are you trying to avoid/solve?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to reuse the document in all test cases. Also trying to follow the DRY principle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197447/discussion-between-volpym-and-jb-nizet).

Comment: Not violating the DRY principle would simply consist in writing a method that fetches and parses the document, and use that method in every test case, instead of copying and pasting the same fetching and parsing code everywhere.